# How to access a casper-rw loop file in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, mount, usb-storage

I'm booting BackTrack off a USB harddrive and writing dumps to a persistent casper-rw file.

Is there a way I can mount the drive and read the data from Windows?

Edit: Here is a description of [casper](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/) "persistent linux".